# Set SPARQL of queries from a series of items

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I currently have a set of ~100 Wikidata items on artists [Q1234, Q2345, Q3456, ... ] that I have to use in order to extract different properties (place/date of birth/death, labels etc.)
I tried iterating through the list and creating a query for each but I am currently facing a bit blockage since many are returning Error 429 (Too Many Requests).

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 ()
index.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query='...' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:51881' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Is there a way in which I can insert the set of items straight in the query?

```
var subquery =      'SELECT DISTINCT ?nameLabel ?cityBLabel ?countryBLabel ?cityDLabel ?countryDLabel ?dateBLabel ?dateDLabel \n' +
                    'WHERE\n' +
                    '{\n' +
                    '       :' + item + ' rdfs:label ?name; \n' +
                    '                wdt:P19 ?cityB; \n' +
                    '                wdt:P20 ?cityD; \n' +
                    '                wdt:P569 ?dateB; \n' +
                    '                wdt:P570 ?dateD. \n' +
                    '       ?cityB wdt:P17 ?countryB .\n' +
                    '       ?cityD wdt:P17 ?countryD .\n' +
                    '       SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". } \n' +
                    '       FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?name), "EN")) \n' +
                    '}\n';
```

For example in the query above, instead of creating and running one query for each `item`, is there a SPARQL command where I can include the whole set ([Q1234, Q2345, Q3456, ... ]) and have it iterate through all of them in one run?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps by using [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data)?

Comment: Either `VALUES` or `FILTER IN`

Comment: *facepalm* i don't know how I missed it in their documentation, sorry, I feel like a retard now! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either a [`FILTER IN`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-in) or [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data) clause for this.

(created community wiki answer from comments)